# Android: Difference between User vs System App development

Tags: android

How can I develop a system application? 
How does it differ from user application development? 
What are special privileges available for system level application that are not available in user level applications?

Is there any difference in submission process of User and System Application?

Is there any restriction in specifying my application as system level application?

Comment: what are system apps according to you?

Comment: When I use 'android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES' in android manifest file for granting permission, it says permission is only granted to system app